# Syncing Large Amounts of Files Between 2 Windows Computers

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync

I have 2 Windows 10 computers in different countries. Both are identical setups hardware wise, same drives layout, etc. Each computer contains about 5TB of data, divided over various drives.

Now I like keeping things pretty much identical on both computers. Every time I travel between countries, I take a very large portable HD, with the new files. This is quite a pain in the *** to do every time. As it's not just new files, but also changes to current files/folders.

Is there a way that when new files arrive or files change on PC1, that PC2 downloads those files from PC1. And also the other way around.

Dropbox and other similar services would be perfect of course, but not for this huge amount of data. Also with multiple drives, it wouldn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that BitTorrent Sync could probably do what you're looking for. It's free for syncing a maximum of 10 top-level folders containing unlimited subfolders, or there's an annual subscription fee for syncing an unlimited number of top-level folders. But both computers would have to be up and running and connected to the Internet at the same time, at least part of the time. (Either that, or you'd have to *also* sync with other computers that are. I suppose you could also schedule your computers to shut down a week or so after your departure and just leave them running with the screen locked.) But if both computers are frequently online at the same time, BitTorrent Sync could be your ticket.

If you were able to set up a secure, stable network connection between the two computers, you might be able to use FreeFileSync with RealTimeSync as well. I don't know anything about this, but if your computers have dynamically assigned IP addresses, it sounds like a hassle.

You might be best served by getting a 6TB or 8TB hard drive, and either (a) getting a nice, high-bandwidth-connection external-drive enclosure for it, or (b) getting a good storage/travel case for it and adding mobile drive racks to your two computers. Mount the drive on your computers and use FreeFileSync to two-way sync data-file folders between the computers and the drive. Once FreeFileSync has completed a first run on each computer and its initial databases are built up, its two-say sync should replicate file and folder deletions, moves, and renamings in addition to new and updated files and folders. If your drive-letter assignments and data-folder structures are truly identical on both computers, you might even be able to use the exact same FreeFileSync batch job on both computers.

You can use FreeFileSync's RealTimeSync component to run your batch job automatically, in background, in real time. RealTimeSync monitors its associated FreeFileSync batch job's folder pairs and launches the batch job whenever it detects a change. When the batch job is through running, it exits, and RealTimeSync resumes monitoring. Regular-sized data files can get copied and copy-verified in as little as 15-20 seconds after the file is saved. (How long it takes depends on a number of variables.)

There are two side benefits to this approach, beyond keeping data on your two computers synced:

- You will have an additional backup of all of your data.
- You can have FreeFileSync automatically generate backups of any files it replaces or deletes as a result of a sync. It can maintain a single backup, periodically versioned backups (e.g., a maximum of one backup per changed file per hour or per day or per week), or comprehensively versioned backups (every previous version of a given file). And you can set these backup methods on a per-folder-pair basis, so you could, for example, maintain comprehensively versioned backups for folders containing your normal-sized important files, fewer or only one backup per file for folders containing huge files, and no backups at all for folders containing unimportant files.

On the downside:

- Immigration and Customs Enforcement and Homeland Security reportedly still seize computers, drives, cell phones, etc., at the border without warrants or probable cause, even though federal courts have started ruling against them. It hopefully wouldn't happen to you, but it would be unfortunate if it did.
- Although FreefileSync is remarkably powerful and is very reliable and easy to use once properly set up, it's thinly documented, its interface is initially confusing, and its learning curve is not for the faint of heart. (However, persistence pays off.)

*A final caveat:*

- *Always* test new FreeFileSync jobs (batch or simple), and existing jobs poised to run on different computers or with different drives mounted, by clicking the *Compare* button and carefully examining the list of proposed actions *before* you click the Synchronize button!